# android:unzip download file

Tags: android

Hi have create from window 7 and put that in server.Now i am downloading the file from server into my SD card.but when i start to unzip it show the error,

```
 java.util.zip.ZipException: EOCD not found; not a Zip archive?
```

the code i have use for unzip is

```
private void unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, ZipEntry entry,
                String outputDir) throws IOException {


            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                createDir(new File(outputDir, entry.getName()));
                return;
            }

            File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
            if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
                createDir(outputFile.getParentFile());
            }

            log("Extracting: " + entry);
            BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                    zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
            BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

            try {
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
```

But when i directly import the file into ddms it work file.

Can anyone know how to resolve the issue then please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi,i found out that my download was not working perfect, thank you for support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(
                zipfile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(
                    unzippath
                            + ze.getName());
            for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                fout.write(c);
            }

            zin.closeEntry();
            fout.close();

        }
        zin.close();
```

Try this .. This will solve your problem i guess.

Comment: hi,i found out that  while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) .. return null so not going in while loop can please tell what wrong with code

Comment: make sure that "zipfile" pointing to proper path containing the zip file.Use log to trace it..

Comment: can please give the code i using the from SD card,File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
//      + "/images/"+DownloadService.IMAGE_ZIP);

Comment: Hi @Nemo, Why write FOR statement? I checked your code. It worked correctly without for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `ZipInputStream` example given in the [doc here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class ZipUtil {

  public static void unzip(File archive, File path) throws IOException{
    ZipInputStream zip = null;
    String fileName = null;
    try{
      if(!path.exists()){
        path.mkdirs();
      }
      zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(archive));
      ZipEntry zipEntry; 
      while((zipEntry=zip.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
        fileName = zipEntry.getName();
        final File outputFile = new File(path, fileName); 
        writeToStream(new BufferedInputStream(zip), new FileOutputStream(outputFile), false);
        zip.closeEntry();
      }
      zip.close();
      zip = null;
    }finally{
      if(zip != null){
        try{ zip.close(); } catch(Exception e){}
      }
    }
  }
  public static void writeToStream(InputStream in , OutputStream out, boolean closeOnExit) throws IOException 
  {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
    for (int c = in.read(bytes); c != -1; c = in.read(bytes)) {
      out.write(bytes,0, c);
    }
    if(closeOnExit){
      in.close();
      out.close();
    }
  }
  public static String writeToString(InputStream stream) throws java.io.IOException{
        StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream,"utf-8"));
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        int numRead=0;
        while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
            String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
            fileData.append(readData);
            buf = new char[1024];
        }
        reader.close();
        return fileData.toString();
    }
}
```